# Is there a gspread call to refresh an importrange() import?

Tags: google-sheets, gspread

I am importing some rows from a sheet A into sheet B using the =importrange() function. I am using the python gspread library to read sheet B. The problem I'm having is if I don't leave sheet B open in a browser somewhere, then changes to sheet A are not seen by my code via gspread.

Is there a gspread API call that will trigger the importrange() refresh? Or is there a better way to do this? In our use case, sheet B needs restricted user access and sheet A can be editable by a broader set of people.

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your actual situation from your question, in your situation, how about directly retrieving the values from "Sheet A" using gspread instead of "importrange"?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, I could do that. But this is for a fire emergency alerts system, and it's fire season. So I am trying to find a way to do this for now that requires the fewest code changes to the code base, to minimize the risk of breakage.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From `Yes, I could do that. But this is for a fire emergency alerts system, and it's fire season. So I am trying to find a way to do this for now that requires the fewest code changes to the code base, to minimize the risk of breakage.`, you cannot use a workaround for directly retrieving the values from "Sheet A" instead of "importrange". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, I am trying to minimize the new code added during fire season. I would prefer a solution on the google sheets app side.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.